# PHP preg_replace giving empty string

Tags: php

I am trying to replace some strings, however it's not working.

```
$content = get_the_content();
$content = wp_strip_all_tags($content);
$thingsToReplace = array ('/\s+/','/\\\\/', '"');
$toReplaceWith = array (' ',' ','\"');
var_dump($content); //here it works fine
$content = preg_replace( $thingsToReplace, $toReplaceWith, $content);

var_dump($content); //here it gives an empty string
```

I tried to troubleshoot it with `var_dump()` and the above is my finding.

What am I doing wrong? Can you please help to fix the issue?

Thank you

Comment: Please go and enable proper PHP error reporting, resp. the WP debug mode. PHP can tell you what is actually wrong here right away.

Comment: [02-Oct-2020 11:14:45 UTC] PHP Warning:  preg_replace(): No ending delimiter '"' found in single.php on line 42
Should it be written this way? `array ('/\s+/','/\\\\/', '/"/');`

Comment: Yes, of course, it has to be a valid regular expression, same as the first two.